# Unable to start Kestrel with 'dnx web', says "current runtime target framework is not compatible"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dnx, coreclr, kestrel-http-server

There are a lot of similar questions on SO, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem. It's evident I'm not familiar enough with .NET Core yet... )

I have a strict ASP.NET Core app, and I'm trying to start the **Kestrel** web server using the **dnx web** command, but it fails because it seems the active framework target is **dnx451** (instead of **dnxcore50**).

My **global.json** looks like:

```
 {
   "projects": [ "FolderName", "src", "test" ], // What IS the actual project name?

  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-rc1-update2",
    "runtime":  "coreclr", 
    "architecture": "x86"
  }
}
```

Excerpts from **project.json**:

```
    "commands": {
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls=http://*:8000/"
    },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnxcore50": { }
  }
```

Any finally, in **launchSettings.json**:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "web": {
      "commandName": "web",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "launchUrl": "http://localhost:8000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Hosting:Environment": "Development"
      },
      "sdkVersion": "dnx-coreclr-win-x86.1.0.0-rc1-update2"
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I can see, the dependencies in **project.json** match the SDK version:

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNet": "1.0.0-rc1",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
  }
```

However, when I run **dnx web** I get the following:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The current runtime target framework is not compatible with 'Okaymaker.Web'.
Current runtime target framework: 'DNX,Version=v4.5.1 (dnx451)'
 Version:      1.0.0-rc1-16609
 Type:         Clr
 Architecture: x86
 OS Name:      Windows
 OS Version:   10.0
 Runtime Id:   win10-x86

Please make sure the runtime matches a framework specified in project.json
```

Not sure why it says the current target framework is **dnx451**? I guess I can run **dnx use** before running **dnx web**, but I was under the impression that the config should handle the settings for me?

Here's what I see if I run **dnvm list**:

```
Active Version           Runtime Architecture Location                         Alias
------ -------           ------- ------------ --------                         -----
       1.0.0-beta8       clr     x64          C:\Users\TedNyberg\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta8       clr     x86          C:\Users\TedNyberg\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta8       coreclr x64          C:\Users\TedNyberg\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-beta8       coreclr x86          C:\Users\TedNyberg\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x64          C:\Users\TedNyberg\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 clr     x86          C:\Users\TedNyberg\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x64          C:\Users\TedNyberg\.dnx\runtimes
       1.0.0-rc1-update1 coreclr x86          C:\Users\TedNyberg\.dnx\runtimes
  *    1.0.0-rc1-update2 clr     x86          C:\Users\TedNyberg\.dnx\runtimes default
       1.0.0-rc1-update2 coreclr x86          C:\Users\TedNyberg\.dnx\runtimes
```

**Edit:** Seems these problems can be resolved/avoided by installing **Visual Studio 2015 Update 3** *and* the updated **tooling for .NET Core**, both available at: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows

Comment: Couple of points, first why don't you upgrade to RTM instead of RC1? You don't even have RC2 here. Seems redundant to stick with beta software when the real stuff is out there. Secondly, `dnx` isn't used any more, you should use `dotnet`.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG! I ran `dnvm upgrade`, but it just downloads the RC... I'm feeling way out on thin ice right now. :) I'll begin by installing VS 2015 **Update 3**, just realized I haven't yet.

Comment: Not sure you can upgrade with command line. Safer to upgrade Visual Studio to update 3 and install via there.

Comment: Thanks again! Yeah, I just realized I was still on Update 2. :/

Comment: here is all dependencies, that you need to have/install https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows

Comment: dnx dnvm dnu are all dead. Use dotnet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `dnvm use` to set the current runtime to coreclr. VisualStudio was not smart enough but the published scripts where smart enough to build a shell script to statically select the right engine.

This was a confirmed design flaw of RC1 (sorry for being to lazy to search the video notes from the ASP.NET Community Standup) and got fixed as part of the `dotnet` command line interface.